# postgreSQL to AWS Aurora PostgreSQL Data Replication

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, amazon-aurora

I am in the process of migrating a couple of applications from on-prem datacenter to AWS and this also includes migrating PostgreSQL to Aurora PostgreSQL. I have tried DMS but it gives a lot of errors. Stream replication is not possible as you cannot access Aurora instance using ssh.

I need some suggestions on what can be an alternative approach.

Comment: I assume you have seen this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Migrating.RDSPostgreSQL.Replica.html

Comment: Yes, I have seen that but it talks about RDS PostgreSQL instance for which AWS provide a mechanism for enabling streaming replication. However, my case is I am having an on-prem PostgreSQL DB required to be migrated to AWS Aurora without or with minimal downtime.